# Hadoop/Elastic Map Reduce with binary executable?

Tags: python, matlab, amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing and distributed image processing application using hadoop streaming, python, matlab, and elastic map reduce. I have compiled a binary executable of my matlab code using the matlab compiler. I am wondering how I can incorporate this into my workflow so the binary is part of the processing on Amazon's elastic map reduce?

It looks like I have to use the Hadoop Distributed Cache?

The code is very complicated (and not written by me) so porting it to another language is not possible right now.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is not exactly an answer to your Hadoop question, but I couldn't resist not asking why you don't execute your processing jobs on the Grid resources? There are proven solutions for executing compute intensive workflows on the Grid. And as far as I know matlab runtime environment is usually available on these resources. You may also consider using the Grid especially if you are in academia.

Good luck

Comment: the reason i am not using the grid resource is because this port to hadoop is the first step to converting the code to java or python and then implementing the entire system in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

Joseph,

I've just asked a similar, but more general version of your question.  Hopefully we'll get some answers. ;)

[Hadoop Streaming: Mapper 'wrapping' a binary executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113798/hadoop-streaming-mapper-wrapping-a-binary-executable)

- Nick